# Ubuntu 22.04 - no GUI on Huawei/Xfusion RH2288H V3

Tags: 22.04

I have installed Ubuntu (also tried Ubuntu server), but I have no GUI. I tried to install it manualy, but I still do not have it. Is someone here used RH2288H V3 (or smiliar from their line) and Ubuntu?

I get the black screen with a "_" cursor blinking.

it is really wierd, as I have installed ubuntu on many machines and the GUI alwayes worked. on this particular server I have has installed Debian 11 earlier and the GUI worked.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: server has no gui(by default) so it wont run. have you tried a different shell?
press ctrl+alt+F2 or other F-Keys. see if anything gives you a shell prompt. 
should you find a shell, login. run sudo startx and see what happens

Comment: I have tried to install gdm3 and desktop environment manually on top of my ubuntu server install. I get the promt no problem and startx fails. server terminated with error (1), but the xorg.0.log and xorg.0.log.old files are empty. I also tried  to install ubuntu desktop and first time ever GUI did not start for me. Same result.

Comment: I did a typo when nano'ing - but still cant find any errors and its hard to paste the content here

Comment: that seems to be a driver issue as Debian 11 works with no problem - I can install XFCE4 and GNOME easily right during install